# Is it correct to say: "to seat on each side of X"?

Tags: grammar, phrase-usage

Example sentence:

> I suggested we choose a seat at the back. **Sitting on each side of
>   the barbacue stove**, we ordered pork belly, beef liver, and lamb
>   slices.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The sentence is grammatically correct, but there is one problem. I think you mean to say you and your companion are sitting **at** each side  of the barbecue. If you were sitting **on** the side of the barbecue stove, you would be cooking your rear!